# error ubxtool : failed to import gps,check PYTHONPATH

Tags: python

I want to use ubxtool.

```
jhkim@***:~$ ubxtool
```

ubxtool: failed to import gps, check PYTHONPATH

---

gpsd-3.21 , ubuntu 18.04
How do I solve it?

Comment: As you built this yourself, can you please post the contents of the `ubxtool` file so we can see what we are dealing with? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are [some](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=ubxtool&literal=1) [clues](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=ubxtool) that `ubxtool` is available only since Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, with `gpsd-3.20`.

So you have to backport it manually [from 20.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal-updates/gpsd) to 18.04 LTS by following the method below:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gpsd
sudo apt-get install build-essential dpkg-dev python3-all-dev python3-all-dbg dh-apparmor dh-exec asciidoc

cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/scons/scons_3.1.2-2_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./scons_3.1.2-2_all.deb

mkdir -p ~/Downloads/gpsd
cd ~/Downloads/gpsd

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gpsd/gpsd_3.20.orig.tar.xz
tar -xf gpsd_3.20.orig.tar.xz
cd gpsd-3.20
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gpsd/gpsd_3.20-8ubuntu0.2.debian.tar.xz
tar -xf gpsd_3.20-8ubuntu0.2.debian.tar.xz
mv gpsd_3.20-8ubuntu0.2.debian.tar.xz ../

dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us

sudo apt-get install ../*gps*.deb
```

And as the result you will get `ubxtool` with its python binding:

> ```
> $ ubxtool -V
> ubxtool: Version 3.20
> ```

Comment: Thank you but  I have a problem. this command" $ ubxtool  -V " ->" ubxtool: ERROR: need gps module version 3.21, got 3.20"

Comment: I would suggest to remove yours 3.21 with some kind of `sudo make uninstall` inside its source code and retry with my method.

Comment: I removed my gpsd 3.21 version . You said, remove some kind of **sudo make uninstall** inside its source code. how to remove it?

Comment: I mean "inside source code" *directory*.